# The calculation of the homology and cohomology groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Although I have read something on algebraic topology, I still have problems calculating the homology and cohomology groups.

This is one of the problems I have encountered.

> Let $V = \oplus_{i=1}^6 \mathbb Cv_i$ be a vector space of dimension $6$ over $\mathbb C$. For $i,j \in \{1,2, \cdots, 6\}$, let $a_{i,j}: V \rightarrow V$ be a $\mathbb C$-linear map with $a_{i,j}v_k = \delta_{j,k}v_i$, where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta. Let $\mathcal F(V)$ be the variety of full flags over $V$, i.e., $\mathcal F(V)$ consists of 
>   $$F: \quad 0=F_0 \subseteq F_1 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq F_6 = V,$$
>   where $\dim F_i=i$ for $i=1,2,\cdots, 6$. Let $W_2 = \mathbb Cv_1 \oplus \mathbb Cv_3$ and $W_4 = \oplus_{i \in \{1,3,5,6\}}\mathbb Cv_i$ be two subspaces of $V$. Define a subspace $X$ of $\mathcal F(V)$ by: for $F\quad(:=0=F_0 \subseteq F_1 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq F_6=V) \in \mathcal F(V)$, $F \in X$ if and only if $F$ satisfies:
>    $\dim(F_4 \cap W_4) \geq 3$, $\dim (F_2 \cap W_2) \geq 1$, and
>   $(a_{1,2}+a_{3,4})F_4 \subseteq F_2 \subseteq W_4$.
>   Then how can the homology and cohomology groups of $X$ be calculated? It seems impossible for me to do trianglulation over $X$. In particular, How can I prove $H_2(X;\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z^5$ and $H^{12}(X, \mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z^7$?

If this question is too simple, please give me some hint or some advice on learning algebraic topology or the calculation of homology and cohomology groups.

(N. Spaltenstein, The fixed point set of a unipotent transformation on the flag manifold, Nederl. Akad. Wetensch. Proc. Ser. A 79=Indag. Math. 38(1976), no. 5, 452-456.)